# Consistent spacing in Exam package?

Tags: exam

In the following example, I am not really happy with the indent.

[image]

IMHO the indent should be as follow:

- Header aligned with the problem name
- No `parindent` for the text of the question
- No indent for the sub question `(a)`
- No indent for the answerline

Where can I configure this in the exam package?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\firstpageheader{Exam}{}{}
\runningheader{Exam}{}{}

\qformat{
  \large\textbf{Problem \thequestiontitle}
  \quad (\thepoints)\hfill
  \vrule depth 1.5em width 0pt
}

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{Foobar}[10]
    In the following...\par
    \begin{parts}
        \part What is foo?
        \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the 1st issue, remove the trailing space: `\qformat{%`

Comment: See Section 4.10 Customizing the list parameters in the exam documentation (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `exam` has some hooks to insert commands into the lists. Initially defined as `\newcommand\questionshook{}`,
`\newcommand\partshook{}` and others, can be activated with

`\renewcommand\questionshook{<newcomands>}`

`\renewcommand\partshook{<newcomands>}`, etc.

The only solution I found to change the indentation of "In the following ..." was to insert before a negative space. Hope this is acceptable.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{showframe}   % show margins

\renewcommand{\partshook}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
\def\makelabel##1{\hskip-\leftmargin##1}%   
}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{% added <<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\firstpageheader{Exam}{}{}
\runningheader{Exam}{}{}

\qformat{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\large\textbf{Problem \thequestiontitle}\quad (\thepoints)\smallskip \\}% changed <<<<<<<<<
}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{questions}
        \titledquestion{Foo}[10]
        \hspace*{-\leftmargin}In the following... % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
            \begin{parts}
            \part What is foo?
            \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
            \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
            \part What is bar?
            \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
            \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}

    \begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{Bar}[15]
    \hspace*{-\leftmargin}In the following...\par
    \begin{parts}
        \part What is bar?
        \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
    \end{parts}
    \end{questions}

    \begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{Baz}[20]
    \hspace*{-\leftmargin}In the following...\par
    \begin{parts}
        \part What is baz?
        \fillwithdottedlines{1cm}
    \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```